# Custom TagHelpers not rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a custom TagHelper defined in the following code:

```
namespace TJ.Website.Core.TagHelpers { 

[HtmlTargetElement("pager", Attributes = "total-pages, current-page, link-url")]
public class PagerTagHelper : TagHelper {

    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName("link-url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output) {
        output.TagName = "div";
        output.PreContent.SetContent("<ul class=\"link-list\">");

        var items = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 1; i <= TotalPages; i++) {
            var li = new TagBuilder("li");

            var a = new TagBuilder("a");
            a.MergeAttribute("href", $"{Url}?page={i}");
            a.MergeAttribute("title", $"Click to go to page {i}");

            a.InnerHtml.Append(i.ToString());

            if (i == CurrentPage) {
                a.AddCssClass("active");
            }

            li.InnerHtml.Append(a.InnerHtml.ToString());

            items.AppendLine(li.ToString());
        }
        output.Content.SetContent(items.ToString());
        output.PostContent.SetContent("</ul>");
        output.Attributes.Clear();
        output.Attributes.Add("class", "pager");
    }
}
}
```

this is my _ViewImports.cs.html page

```
@using TJ.Website.Core
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, TJ.Website.Core
@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration     TelemetryConfiguration
```

In my View `Views\Home\Index.cshtml` I want to do this

```
<pager total-pages='6' current-page='1'></pager>
```

But it is not rendering... / recognized in my view
My Assembly / Projectname is TJ.Website.Core

Please help

Comment: looks to me like you have 3 required attributes and are only adding 2 of them. fyi, I have a nice pager already built here https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.Web.Pagination

Comment: also you have not added the HtmlAttributeName for 2 of your properties

Comment: Thank you Joe Audette, I'm very happy!